# How do I set up Pulseaudio to work in Multi-Seat?

Tags: 10.04, pulseaudio, multiseat

How do i set up pulseaudio for a two User Multi-Seat setup on Ubuntu 10.04LTS?
I have a HDA Intel device. I was wondering if it were possible to use the separate sound outputs to different seats. I have four outputs and two inputs; microphone and line-in. Is it possible to use this one Device or do I have to get a Separate sound card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this: http://disjunkt.com/jd/2010/en/multiseat-linux/multiseat-linux-system-wide-pulseaudio-for-routing-sounds-109/